# how to get client unique ip in laravel or anything unique that can identify the user device

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, networking

i need to get anything that can be unique and related to the user's device. I have used this method to get the client's IP

```
    $worker_ip = $request->IP();
```

it works well, but if many users share the same WIFI, it returns the same number. so I need to know if anything can be unique I can fetch to identify the client's device

Comment: you can modify your frontend? generate a hash and send to backend ?

Comment: People can update their browsers, or use different browsers, clear their cache or sessions, or even move their laptop to a new location and thus get a new ip address.  Maybe their internet goes out and they power cycle their modem and get a new ip. There's not really a reliable way to identify the user's device and recognize them again later. I assume we're talking a browser here and don't have access to things like a mac address. Read into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint you might also look into for example something like this: https://fingerprint.com/demo/

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking for a unique thing you can follow along**

```php
$uid = uniqid() # 62b270bce4f9e
```

- This will give you a unique identifier for each user

Answer (score -1):

The IP itself doesn't identify an user device as you said.

If you want to create some kind of authentication system where you can see the signed devices you will have to store more than one information.

You can store the `User-Agent` request header, the `location`, `IP`, and the `last login time`. If it is a mobile device you can get the `model`, `name` etc.

And if you want to invalidate the signed device it will need to be attached to a token authentication system and the token will have to be invalidated.

Comment: But this can be used to identify user device. IP also doesn't identify an user device.

Comment: I have 6 computers, each with the same version of firefox, all in a home setting, i.e. behind a router that uses NAT ... how can an IP and/or user-agent identify which of the 6 computers I'm using?

Comment: So we should agree that the question is malformed and we can't have a perfect answer

Comment: the question is not malformed - it's a legitimate question, with an answer that doesn't involve an even more common identifier than an IP address (user-agent), and, on edit, adding `location` to the list of things to use to identify a unique visitor? what even is `location`? you think you can just get a requests location? as for model and name of mobile device - again, how does a server just "get" these things?

Comment: A server get these things from the client. If you have a better idea to identify the client's device you can share with us. How does Netflix, Amazon and other big tech companies identify our signed devices? You will see your IP, User-Agent and location on this section of their sites.